# Suspend browsing while AJAX scripts are running?

Tags: ajax, client-side, server-side

I have some very complex PHP/MySQL-based AJAX routines that run at certain points in my application. The problem I continually run into is that the user browses away from the base page while the AJAX routine is still running and that kills the XHR request on the spot with an error.

Maybe this is a question of client-side vs server-side? Do I need to take my more time-consuming AJAX routines and make them part of the main script? Maybe there's a way to suspend all browsing while any AJAX routine is running that I just haven't found? I know I could always throw a "Loading / Waiting / Go get a sandwich" dialog up but I find those terribly annoying and so will my users.

Any help / suggestions / philosophies appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot suspend browsing per-se, but you can cough up a decent looking 'wait, loading' block on top of a full-page shadow that warns the user that things are happening. That, or disable every href on the page via javascript, which is hardly advisable. :)

Other than that, you have no control over the client whatsoever.

P.S.: If by "dialog" you mean an alert, kill that thought with fire immediately.

Comment: I'm a jQuery nut, so 100% of my AJAX calls are with `$.get`, `$.post` or `$.getJSON`. The nice thing is, I can use the jQuery-UI `dialog` widget to support the app but tossing a **modal** up there every time a long AJAX routine is running would result in some nasty _to the webmaster_ feedback.

Comment: @DevlshOne, Yeah, that's what I was referring to. Just making sure you don't shoot yourself in the foot. Obstructive modals are evil. Seamless ones are unavoidable in your case though.

Answer (score 0):

I think that requests that wait for a long time to get a response beat the ajax concept of "behind the scene" communication.

I would suggest you split your action into a command ("please do this") and a status ("are you done yet??").  This way you can update the page when the server is done doing its thing, and not hold on to the request channel for no good reason (this is also good for concurrent user support, of which you will run out of pretty soon if every visitor will hold your connection for a long time).